# How to correct cloth physics?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Alright, so I work in a print lab and have recently been asked to make some product models for our website. One of our products is a table cloth. I have made the plane the proper size and shape, and have a simple cube which represents an 6' table. At this point, there are no issues, the simulation is just slightly glitchy. However, when I resize the table to 8' (our cloths fit both sizes) the cloth seems raised on the sides. I'm not sure how to correct this. A screenshot is included below.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get it to lie flat rather than look like there is something on the table underneath?

Update: Here is the mesh I used for the cloth

[image]

Comment: Can you post your mesh? Try applying the scale of the cloth

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to resolve the issue. It turned out the impression was due to my vertex group. I made a large selection of what would be on top of the table, and the sides of the mesh which were not part of that group were being raised as a result (for some reason). I deleted the vertex group and it now looks the way it is supposed to.